# Searching inside a hash of hashes, and returning the keys

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash:

```
{1=>{"label"=>"New", "color"=>"#whatver"}, 2=>{"label"=>"In-progress", "color"=>"#whatever"}, 3=>{"label"=>"Closed", "color"=>"#whatever"}}
```

And I have an array like: `['New', 'In-progress']`

I need to return the keys `[1, 2]` in an array from that hash.

What I did try:

```
labels = ['New', 'In-progress']
labels.map { |label| statuses.detect { |hash| hash.second[:label] == label }.first }
# => [1, 2]
```

Which is correct and the exact thing I want, but is there a more direct way of doing this?

Comment: When you give an example, please assign a variable to each input value (e.g, `h = { 1=>...}` and `arr = ['New'...]`) so that readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define them.

Comment: I somehow got that wrong. My apology. Still, don't you think it would have been better to have assigned the variables when you first mentioned the two objects? Had you done so you wouldn't have had to repeat the array and the meaning of `statuses` would be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not that much shorter but clearer in terms of what you are trying to achieve:

```
h.select { |_, value| ['New', 'In-progress'].include?(value['label']) }.keys
```

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {1=>{"label"=>"New", "color"=>"#whatver"},
     2=>{"label"=>"In-progress", "color"=>"#whatever"},
     3=>{"label"=>"Closed", "color"=>"#whatever"}}
labels = ['New', 'In-progress']

h.select { |_,v| (v.values & labels).any? }.keys
  #=> [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ndn's answer, here are two more ways to extract the desired keys.

```
data = {1=>{"label"=>"New", "color"=>"#whatver"}, 2=>{"label"=>"In-progress", "color"=>"#whatever"}, 3=>{"label"=>"Closed", "color"=>"#whatever"}}

labels = ['New', 'In-progress']

data.map{|k, h| k if labels.include?(h["label"])}.compact
# => [1, 2]

data.dup.delete_if{|_, h| !labels.include?(h["label"])}.keys
# => [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
h = {1=>{"label"=>"New", "color"=>"#whatver"}, 
   2=>{"label"=>"In-progress", "color"=>"#whatever"}, 
   3=>{"label"=>"Closed", "color"=>"#whatever"}}

labels = ['New', 'In-progress']

result = h.select do |k, hash|
    # Check if any label is part of values array
    labels.any? {|label| hash.values.include?(label)}
end

p result.keys
#=> [1,2]
```